# Python input() box position in Jupyter notebook is out of sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple function that I use to read the contents of a text file into a Python variable. I use it to import SQL queries. The function takes a parameter that is the path and name of the text file and allows several attempts to get the name right, allowing for typos or mis-spellings. By default, this parameter is set to None. If the file can't be found, the function prints an error message and presents an input() box to allow a new path and filename to be entered. The function then either returns the string (representing the SQL query) or returns None if the file can't be found.

The function is:

```
def readQueryFromFile(queryPathAndFileName = None):

    maxAttempts = 3

    for i in range(maxAttempts):

        if (queryPathAndFileName is None) or (i > 0):

            queryPathAndFileName = input("Enter path and filename for text file contains SQL query: ")

        try:
            tempFileObject = open(queryPathAndFileName)
            tempQuery = tempFileObject.read()
            tempFileObject.close()
            break

        except FileNotFoundError as e:

            print("\nA FileNotFoundError occurred.\nError number {0}: {1}. File named \'{2}\' does not exist at that location.".format(e.args[0],e.args[1],queryPathAndFileName))

            if i < (maxAttempts-1):
                print('\nPlease re-enter path and filename details.\n')    # Only say 'Please try again' if not last attempt.

            else:
                # If query file can't be found then set tempQuery to None
                print('\nFailed to find file containing query after {0} attempts.\n'.format(i+1))
                tempQuery = None

    return tempQuery
```

The function could be called in a Jupyter notebook cell using:

```
myQuery = readQueryFromFile(queryPathAndFileName = '/geosgnasoeg/asgogeso.sges')
```

Clearly, the path and file name is nonsensical and the function presents an error message and a prompt to enter the path and file name again. However, the error messages appear after the input box is displayed as follows:

```
Enter path and filename for text file contains SQL query: |________|

A FileNotFoundError occurred.
Error number 2: No such file or directory. File named '/geosgnasoeg/asgogeso.sges' does not exist at that location.

Please re-enter path and filename details.
```

Having the messages appear out of sequence can be confusing. Interestingly, if a second incorrect path and file name is entered, the output realigns itself correctly.

I'm using a Mac running El Capitan and this issues occurs in both Safari and Firefox.

Is there a way to force the output displayed in Jupyter notebook to appear in the correct (i.e. sequential) order?

Comment: I'm confused, what is the correct order?

Comment: Apologies. The 'correct' order would be the order in which the commands are encountered in the function.