# Jupyter Notebook Input Line Executed Before Print Statement

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hello I am working on improving my python skills in Jupyter Notebook and I am having a frustrating issue.  In a larger piece of code, my input statements are being executed before the print statements although the print statement is first in the code block.  Is there a way to fix this in Jupyter Notebook?  I am doing a tutorial course and want to continue using this IDE.  Please see attached image.

[image: Python Input issue]

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question without an answer: [Python input() box position in Jupyter notebook is out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013247/python-input-box-position-in-jupyter-notebook-is-out-of-sequence). My instinct is there is no answer, this is intentionally designed.

Comment: How does that make sense? Why would this be intentional, if the first line of your code says print that should be printed before the next line of your code no?  Apparently this issue doesn't happen across others users Jupyter Notebooks.  I am running Mac High Sierra with Safari 11.1

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce this behaviour with anaconda 5.1 on Linux. Notebook 5.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198676/jupyter-input-display-print-excute-order-is-chaotic

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3159

Answer (score 3):

When I `flush` the print statement to force it to display, it works for me:

```
print("Welcome", flush = True)
input("yes")
```

Comment: This should be the preferred method of dealing with this issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between two streams. One possible, unsastifying solution is to wait a bit before executing `input`:

```
import time
print("Welcome")
time.sleep(0.05)
input("yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining that a bit and that solution does work for me with times .20 and up.  However, I would have to sprinkle these types of statements throughout my code.  Is there a way to flush the developer environment or reset settings that might fix this issue.